# Pass google maps coordinates to marker

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I am looking to pass a set of coordinates received from two textfields(displayLat and displayLong) and create a marker with the passed in coordinates as the marker location. 
Code so far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function initialize()
    {
    var markersArray = [];          //array to hold the map markers

    function clearOverlays() {      //function to clear the markers from the arrays, deleting them from the map
      for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
      markersArray.length = 0;
    }
    var mapProp = {     //the actual map in the page
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.8978719,-8.471087399999988),     //center of map
      zoom:12,          //zoom level
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP       //kind of map
      };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")        //element ID
      ,mapProp);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {      //what happens when the map is right clicked
        clearOverlays();            //removes current markers form the map
      });

    function placeMarker(location) {        //place marker function, adds marker to passed in location
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map,
      })
      markersArray.push(marker);        //adds new marker to the markers array
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){});           
      ;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {     //listener so when a marker is clicked an infowindow pops up
infowindow.open(map,marker);
      });
    }
    }

    function InputCoords()
    {
    var Inputlat = document.getElementById('displayLat').value;
    var Inputlng = document.getElementById('displayLong').value;
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Inputlat, Inputlng); 

    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML=newLatLng;

    placeMarker(newLatLng); 

    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML="Past var dec";

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
    Lat 1:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="50" name="displayLat" id ="displayLat" value=""><br />
    Long 1:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="50" name="displayLong" id="displayLong" value=""><br />

    <button onclick="InputCoords()">Input Coordinates</button>
    <p id="button1"></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

So far I am passing in the coordinates, converting them into a google.maps.LatLng object but they are not getting passed to the placeMarker function so far as I can tell.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function `InputCoords()` calls function `placeMarker()` which is not visible because it is local to `initialize()` function. You have to place it out of it. And make variables `map` and  `markersArray` global.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zogav/1/edit).

You can also add:

```
map.setCenter(location);
```

to `placeMarker()` function to see marker if location is off the current visible part of map.

Comment: Perfect solution, I had tried putting the InputCoords() and placeMarker() outside initialize() but hadn't noticed the variables needed to be global, thanks very much.

Comment: You have to develop/test with console log open. Message for `map` is not so clear, but for `markersArray` it is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: markersArray is not defined `